# Is it possible that packet captured by tcpdump, but lost in tcp kernel?

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel, tcpdump

```
  1 10:59:11.303358 IP CCC > SSS: S 2325818282:2325818282(0) win 14600 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 2358537033 0,nop,wscale 7>
  2 10:59:11.304131 IP SSS > CCC: S 3397574260:3397574260(0) ack 2325818283 win 14440 <mss 1456,sackOK,timestamp 994572340 2358537033,nop,wscale 9>
  3 10:59:11.305182 IP CCC > SSS: . ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
  4 10:59:11.305280 IP CCC > SSS: . 1:1445(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
  5 10:59:11.305288 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572342 2358537035>
  6 10:59:11.305370 IP CCC > SSS: . 1445:2889(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
  7 10:59:11.305418 IP CCC > SSS: . 2889:4333(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
  8 10:59:11.305422 IP CCC > SSS: . 4333:5777(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
  9 10:59:11.305434 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572343 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 1 {4333:5777}>
 10 10:59:11.305426 IP CCC > SSS: . 5777:7221(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
 11 10:59:11.305439 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572343 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 1 {4333:7221}>
 12 10:59:11.305611 IP CCC > SSS: P 7221:8665(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
 13 10:59:11.305632 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572343 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 1 {4333:8665}>
 14 10:59:11.305617 IP CCC > SSS: . 8665:10109(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
 15 10:59:11.305638 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572343 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 1 {4333:10109}>
 16 10:59:11.305621 IP CCC > SSS: . 10109:11553(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
 17 10:59:11.305643 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572343 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 1 {4333:11553}>
 18 10:59:11.305624 IP CCC > SSS: . 11553:12997(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537035 994572340>
 19 10:59:11.305648 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572343 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 1 {4333:12997}>
 20 10:59:11.306649 IP CCC > SSS: . 12997:14441(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537036 994572342>
 21 10:59:11.306652 IP CCC > SSS: . 14441:15885(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537036 994572342>
 22 10:59:11.306655 IP CCC > SSS: . 15885:17329(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537036 994572342>
 23 10:59:11.306722 IP CCC > SSS: P 17329:18773(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537036 994572343>
 24 10:59:11.306735 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 1445 win 34 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572344 2358537035,nop,nop,sack 2 {17329:18773}{4333:12997}>
 25 10:59:11.306725 IP CCC > SSS: . 1445:2889(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537036 994572343>
 26 10:59:11.306743 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 2889 win 40 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572344 2358537036,nop,nop,sack 2 {17329:18773}{4333:12997}>
 27 10:59:11.306731 IP CCC > SSS: . 2889:4333(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537037 994572343>
 28 10:59:11.306808 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 12997 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572344 2358537037,nop,nop,sack 1 {17329:18773}>
 29 10:59:11.307932 IP CCC > SSS: . 12997:14441(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537038 994572344>
 30 10:59:11.307942 IP SSS > CCC: . ack 14441 win 51 <nop,nop,timestamp 994572345 2358537038,nop,nop,sack 1 {17329:18773}>
 31 10:59:11.308121 IP CCC > SSS: . 18773:20217(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537038 994572344>
 32 10:59:11.308127 IP CCC > SSS: . 20217:21661(1444) ack 1 win 115 <nop,nop,timestamp 2358537038 994572344>
```

From line 6,7,8 tcpdump catched data 1445~5777,
but it still ack with 1445 in line 9.
I suggest that kernel hasn't received that data in time.
But just after line 25, it ack 2889, which make the packet in line 6 seem lost.
So, where does the packet in line 6 go?

I diff two file genated from 'netstat -s' before and after transmission.
The result show that there are bad segments received. Is it the key to my problem?

```
<     4637068 segments received
<     3972086 segments send out
<     118982 segments retransmited
<     40245 bad segments received.
---
>     4637506 segments received
>     3972383 segments send out
>     118989 segments retransmited
>     40402 bad segments received.
29,30c29,30
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I was about to ask the same question when I happened upon this. It mightn't be relevant to you but it is to some people.

Answer (score 3):

If `tcpdump` is pulling data off of the wire directly then yes it can capture datagrams that the kernel may miss. Both the kernel and `tcpdump` will have different data buffers that they are reading in to and if the kernel's buffer fills I would assume that it may drop packets.

This is even more likely if `tcpdump` is being run on a different machine to the machine that is actually receiving the data.

Comment: This is indeed normal behavior, so it's even "will", not "may". Dropping packets is part of the congestion control algorithm.

Comment: I expected so, but since I'm not familiar with the internals of the linux kernels I decided to be a little vague. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Damon What is the reason for dropping packets received, which seems be no benefit to congestion control.

Comment: @hello.co: TCP must do _something_ since not all hosts (nor all routes between identical hosts) have the same bandwidth and buffer sizes. What other means does TCP have but to drop packets? There is no way of knowing how many packets (or how big ones) you can send. Except if you set the don't fragment bit and get an ICMP error (for "how big") or if packets disappear without being acknowledged (for "how many").